# How to debug cordova app with windows phone 10

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, hybrid-mobile-app, windows-10-mobile

I have searched a lot to get its answer. I have a cordova windows application running nokia lumia 925 (windows phone 10). I dont know how to debug it. I tired and researched a lot but didn't get any working solution. i tried **weinre**, it also didn't worked. It didn't even detected the phone. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Open CordovaApp.sln file with preferably Visual Studio 2017 and connect your Lumia to PC by cable. VS should detect it, and at the top of you VS UI you'll be able to choose "Device" as destination for debugging.